# SQL Server full text search catalog not full updated

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

It seems that my Sql Server Full text catalog is not always up to date. I regularly run the script:

```
EXEC sp_fulltext_catalog   'HtmlSearch', 'start_full'
```

After that my catalog is up to date and my search results are fine. Is there somewhere an option that I have to set? And when does the full text update itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server Management Studio, expand *[Database Name] / Storage / Full Text Catalogs*. Right-click your catalog and select *Properties*. Select *Tables/Views* on the left and check whether *Track changes* is set to *Automatic*.

Comment: Thnx it was set to `Do not track changes`. When will it update the catalog? After which period of time?